# Can the Windows 10 download via Windows Update be interrupted?

Tags: windows-update, windows-10-upgrade

Can the Windows 10 download via Windows Update be interrupted? I have seen the Windows Update doing it's thing in the background for a few days now, and I *do* switch off / sleep my computer every day, as any normal person would. Do I have to let my computer run overnight with the automatic sleep settings turned off?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upgrade to Windows 10 I would advice you to get the [Media Creation Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-GB/software-download/windows10) which is provided by Microsoft. You can choose to Upgrade your Windows version from there and set which data should be kept.

This lets you download Windows 10 correctly and it shows a better status of the whole process. I have used it today to upgrade an older Laptop to Windows 10 and it took about 1,5 hours(it depends on your download speed of course). So you might want to give that a try.